# My service doesn't get user id and password from GCP Secret Manager when I am using Spring Cloud release Hoxton-SR5

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud

Has anyone used new Spring Cloud release Hoxton-SR5 with Google Cloud? My service doesn't get user id and password from GCP Secret Manager when I am using Hoxton-SR5. When I changed back to Hoxton-SR3 then it works fine. Is there any tricks for getting data from Google Cloud Secret Manager comparing older version Hoxton-SR3? I am testing the service on my workstation.

application.properties

```
# General settings
server.port=8090

# CRM application and user name from GCP configuration resource
crm.application.id=SYNC_CRM
crm.user.name=${crm-user-name}

# CRM credential username and password from GCP secret manager
crm.credentials.clientId=sync_user
crm.credentials.clientSecret=
crm.credentials.userName=${crm-credentials-userName}
crm.credentials.password=${crm-credentials-password}
crm.credentials.platform=base
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=local
spring.config.location=classpath:application.properties

# Spring Google Cloud properties
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=syncing-development
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:keys/sync-development.json

spring.cloud.gcp.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.config.name=syncing
spring.cloud.gcp.config.profile=development

spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.bootstrap.enabled=true
```

Properties class for credentials

```
package com.sync.common.shared.configurations.properties;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "crm.credentials")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CrmCredentialProperties {
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String platform;
}
```

Configuration class

```
package com.sync.common.shared.configurations;

import com.sync.common.shared.configurations.properties.CrmCredentialProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sync.common")
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    CrmCredentialProperties.class
})
public class CommonConfiguration {
    private CrmCredentialProperties crmCredentialProperties;

    @Autowired
    public CommonConfiguration(CrmCredentialProperties crmCredentialProperties) {
        this.crmCredentialProperties = crmCredentialProperties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code and your properties files?

Comment: When GCP Secret Manager was being added as a [feature](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/2115) of Spring Cloud, there was a reference provided to anyone with any issue so feel free to ask questions on this [here](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud-gcp/Lobby) or you can post a question on Github.